# JMeter: How to get date of last week starting from sunday till saturday?

Tags: date, jmeter, timestamp, increment

The scenario is I need to get last week date in format yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss from last Sunday till Saturday(date will increment by 1 from last week of Sunday till Saturday) and like wise one more is to get date from past 20 weeks(till last week).

How may I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is not very clear so I can provide only a generic solution:

1. Getting the "last Sunday"

   ```
    def calendar = Calendar.instance
    def delta = Calendar.SUNDAY - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, delta)
    log.info('Last Sunday: ' + calendar.time.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
   ```

   [image]
2. Getting all previous "dates" for last 20 weeks:

   ```
    def now = new Date()
    use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
        def twentyWeeksAgo = now - 30.weeks
        def duration = now - twentyWeeksAgo
        1.upto(duration.days, {
            twentyWeeksAgo = twentyWeeksAgo + 1.days
            log.info(twentyWeeksAgo.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
        })
    }
   ```

   [image]

More information:

- [Groovy TimeCategory](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html)
- [Creating and Testing Dates in JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-and-testing-dates-in-jmeter-learn-how)

Comment: I have to add entries for past dates and hence this is the requirement, go to past 20 weeks and start filling forms for that date, then fill for next day like wise till last week saturday.

Comment: ${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,,-P20DT2M,,)} this gives me past 20 days like 2021-04-13 12:08:37 and when I add loop controller for 2 users, it shows 2021-04-13 12:08:37 and 2021-04-13 12:08:37 as 2 dates(both same). What I want is 2021-04-13 12:08:37 and 2021-04-14 12:08:37 as date will increase as 1 day and so on

Comment: This is how the questions need to be asked, thanks.  Just use [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) and [__counter()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) functions combination instead of your hard-coded `20` like `${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,,-P${__intSum(21,-${__counter(FALSE,)},)}DT2M,,)}`